# Create Shortcut on ios programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, shortcut

How to create a shortcut on ios home to access a specific viewcontroller on my application using objective c?

Comment: so you want to create an alias in the list of all iOS applications that will launch your application and go to a specific view controller within your application?

Comment: Yes, so I have mutliple web application in my ios application, my web application run on a webview. I want to have two possibilities to access a web application: via shortcut with all the ios application or accessing my ios application than access a web application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access your apps with a custom schema, like:

```
myApp://....
```

If you register your app to use that schema, every time an app calls that or a webpage starts with that, it will open your app. Then, you can detect that your app was opened like that and open the view you want.

[Apple iOS Custom Schemas](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)

But what you can't do is to create an app/webpage on your home screen programatically from your code, that's not allowed. You can save a webpage from safari in your home, and that webpage will open your app, but not from your app.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so I can't create shortcut for the web applications Embedded in my ios application.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is a little confusing, but I can think of an answer for either of the two scenarios you could be asking about:

If you want to know how to easily access certain view controller code in Xcode more easily, start using tabs in your window (command-T) to have multiple views open at once, just like browsing on the web.

However (and this is more likely) if you want to have access to a view controller in an app, you need to put a UIButton on the viewController you're looking at, and either present the new controller modally:

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or, if your current view controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller:

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: By the way, you need to put either of those code snippets in the method that gets targeted when a button touch event is registered.

Comment: No, it's not that what i'm searching for, my scenario I have multiple web application Embedded in my ios application running on uiwebview, so I'm searching a way to access a web application from ios home screen insead of accessing my ios application than executing my web application.