# How to programmatically create a standalone app on user's homescreen?

Tags: ios

I am looking for a way to create a shortcut on the user's home screen or export a standalone app. The app [Workflow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow-powerful-automation/id915249334?mt=8) in the App Store does this already, I just don't know how they accomplish it. Does anyone know?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. To create a standalone app, you build an app and submit it to the AppStore and people install it. I assume you mean some other thing. You should explain what it is that you would like to do rather than simply referencing some other app. What steps do you want the user to take, and what do you expect to happen after those steps?

Comment: Read the description from the app I linked to. It allows the user to create standalone apps on their homescreen. This is how it appears to the user. On the backend it may just be a shortcut...that is all I am looking for. A shortcut that will open my app with some extra information that I provide.

Comment: I don't think those are real apps. They are probably links to web page snippets that open the app (configured the way the user expects) via a custom URL scheme.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but how do I go about programmatically doing that?

Comment: Yes Its, true !! Does any one know about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you search for has been covered here a lot of times:
[Create Shortcut on ios programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238873/create-shortcut-on-ios-programmatically)
[How could I create a shortcut on desktop in iOS through an app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7577934/1254172)
[iPhone SDK - Add a “Add to Home Screen” button in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838687/1254172)
[Link to Safari “Add to Home Screen” from inside app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28042152/1254172)